# How to target/query exactly the image elements which have their source stored in CSS?

Tags: javascript, filter, reduce, selectors-api, getcomputedstyle

I am using Vite where I store the image's source in the css. In a function, I have to get the source of the image but I am not sure how to pull it from the css. Below is how I selected the img tag and how I stored the img source. How would I write this out in Javascript to put the css content in the array?

```
// JS
this.images = [...document.querySelectorAll('img')];

//css
#firstimage {
  content: url(./assets/img1.jpg);
}
#secondimage {
  content: url(./assets/img1.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Maybe don't store that in CSS. Have a config file that you can import that has that source information instead.

Comment: What is `this` in the context of your JavaScript? Can you share enough of your "*[mcve]*" code that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: The this doesn't matter. I could store that array in a basic variable outside of the scope of my constructor and the problem would be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP needs to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) each image-element of the queried images-only `NodeList` (after casting it into an array type) by its computed `content` style-property with the help of [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

```js
console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll('img')]
    .filter(img => {
      // get the computed style object.
      const cs = window.getComputedStyle(img);
      // access the computed `content` value.
      const value = cs.getPropertyValue('content');
      // test whether `value` contains an URL.
      //  - [https://regex101.com/r/j7nccT/1]
      return (/^url\(.+\)$/).test(value);
    })
);
```

```css
#firstimage {
  content: url(https://picsum.photos/67/100?grayscale);
}
#secondimage {
  content: url(https://picsum.photos/66/99?grayscale);
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 90px!important;
}
```

```html
<img id="firstimage" src="" />
<img src="https://picsum.photos/67/100" />
<img src="https://picsum.photos/66/99" />
<img id="secondimage" src="" />
```

***Edit** ... due to the fact that the above (initial) answer missed one (the most important) of the OP's requirements.*

> *"In a function, I have to **get the source of the image** but I am not sure how to pull it from the css. ... How would I write this ... to put the css content in the array?"*

The firstly provided solution then needs to be changed from a `filter` to a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task where one (as for the former) not just does [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) the `content` value by a simple regex like ... [`^url\(.+\)$`](https://regex101.com/r/j7nccT/1) ... but also (as for the latter) [captures](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) the image-source by a regex like ... [`^url\((?<src>.+)\)$`](https://regex101.com/r/j7nccT/3) ... which features a [named capturing group](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups).

```js
console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll('img')]
    .reduce((result, elm) => {

      // get the computed style object.
      const cs = window.getComputedStyle(elm);

      // access the computed `content` value.
      const value = cs.getPropertyValue('content');

      // test for and capture the image's source.
      //  - [https://regex101.com/r/j7nccT/3]
      const src = (/^url\((?<src>.+)\)$/)
        .exec(value)?.groups?.src ?? null;

      if (src !== null) {
        result.push({
          // create an object of element reference and source.
          elm,
          src: src
            // remove possible leading single/double quote.
            .replace(/^['"]/, '')
            // remove possible trailing single/double quote.
            .replace(/['"]$/, '')
        });
      }
      return result;

    }, [])
);
```

```css
#firstimage {
  content: url(https://picsum.photos/67/100?grayscale);
}
#secondimage {
  content: url(https://picsum.photos/66/99?grayscale);
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 90px!important;
}
```

```html
<img id="firstimage" src="" />
<img src="https://picsum.photos/67/100" />
<img src="https://picsum.photos/66/99" />
<img id="secondimage" src="" />
```

Comment: intense, thank you for the help and expanding my knowledge of js